# Send mail by using Strapi and React.js

Tags: reactjs, strapi

Since one month me and my team are working on a project with React as frontend and Strapi as our backend.

We need to do a form that has to automatically send e-mails by using the Strapi e-mails plugin.

However, we're still beginners with those technologies, and we aren't able to implement this kind of functionnality.
**Is anyone familiar with Strapi and also this plugin ?**

We don't find a lot of tutorials and documentation about it on the web.

Thank your for paying attention.

Comment: We have tried some things but the fact is that all of our sources of documentation are saying different things, especially because of the frequent updates of this cms. We are still students and we have only worked with this kind of technology for this project so we don't really know where to start.

Comment: Please consider the guidelines for asking a good question that are available in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

you can follow instructions of this guide - https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/guides/send-email.html#introduction

You can create a custom route/controller to manage your contact form.

Here is an example - https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/concepts/controllers.html#example

Make sure to create a POST route.

Then in your controller, get your form data with `ctx.request.body`